# Inconsistent Reputation After Merge

Tags: discussion, reputation, merge-accounts, lost-reputation

Mr. Atwood was so kind as to merge my SO accounts today (I had created alternate OpenID by accident). After the merge, though, I seem to have lost reputation and all my 'flair' icons are inconsistent. Pic related.

[image]

I am curious if it's possible to restore my (hard earned!) rep back to where it was prior to the merge and/or if this is just a temporary condition until the various servers/unicorns update their *select sum(reputation)*. Thanks.

**EDIT:**

My reputation seems to have normalized across the different flair icons

[image]

oops I mean

[image]

I'll just grind back to where I was.

Comment: What is the rep reported at the bottom here? http://StackOverflow.com/reputation

Comment: ** total rep 1185 :)

days represented 40
rep cap was reached via rep from upvotes *only* on 0 days
rep cap was exceeded on 0 days

--- it's been at 1250+ for a few days though

Comment: maybe the merge did just cause a rep-recalc that was overdue anyway. That happens when e.g. an upvoted answer of you got deleted (also indirectly by the question it replied to being deleted), or an accepted answer unaccepted.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Probably some question you answered was deleted a while ago, and your (upvoted) answer was deleted with it. Such deletions are not immediately reflected in your reputation, but those deleted upvotes don't count anymore.

An account merge causes your reputation to be recalculated, and then the deleted upvotes won't be counted anymore. (And no, for anybody less than diamond moderators there is no way to find out which questions/answers might have been deleted.)

Answer (score 4):

Did you happen to upvote posts from one ID while logged on as the other? I seriously doubt you would be allowed to keep self-awarded Rep.

Comment: No, but this is a good idea ;)